# Android 11 SSL handshake fails when using Charles Proxy

Tags: android, charles-proxy

Unable to use Charles Proxy with Android devices since the update to 11. I've read the [Configure CAs for debugging](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#TrustingDebugCa) page and verified that the app I'm testing is set up per their instructions. This isn't a problem with iOS running the same app. It seems to only be an Android issue.

I can access the internet when proxying through Charles on Android which to me means the connection is good but when I go to use the app that's when things start to fail.

I'm mostly wondering if anyone else is experiencing this issue? If I can isolate my experience I can hopefully use that rationale to get this issue fixed.

Answer (score 8):

From Android 11, or later, there are new configs in order to make Charles Proxy work:

1. Verify that you install & trust Charles Proxy certificate. You can verify in Settings app -> Security -> Encryption & Credentials -> Trusted Credentials -> User Tab => Make sure Charles Proxy is loaded.
2. You're only able to intercept SSL Proxying **from your own app**, not other apps.
3. In your source code, add res/xml/network_security_config.xml

```
<network-security-config>
    <debug-overrides>
        <trust-anchors>
            <!-- Trust user added CAs while debuggable only -->
            <certificates src="user" />
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </debug-overrides>
    
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>

    <domain-config>
        <!-- Make sure your URL Server here -->
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">your_production_domain</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="user"/>
            <certificates src="system"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

=> Replace your_production_domain with your working domain.

4. Add to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest>
    <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
    </application>
</manifest>
```

---

Read more at https://docs.proxyman.io/debug-devices/android-device

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for your detailed response. I do see a few differences between our `network_security_config.xml` and what you've detailed in your response. I'll try your suggestion and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the 'xxx.pem' to 'xxx.cer', and reinstall

Comment: Yes this worked, when saving certificate from Charles choose .cer format instead of .pem. The .cer one can be installed, but it just silently doesn't work! Install .pem instead.